# concatenate, count and add a colum of values from another table

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql, csv

I have 12 monthly tables. For the sake of simplicity let's say that tables are only 2:

TABLE1

```
| IDA | IDB | TYPE1 | 
| 123 | X   | 90    |
| 123 | X   | 30    |   
| 123 | Y   | 30    |
```

TABLE2

```
| IDA | IDB | TYPE1 |  
| 123 | X   | 90    |
```

First of all I have to create in each table a new ID by concatenating IDA and IDB. I would like to do it in postgresql (using _ between the IDA and IDB values), but I think to be able do it only in bash (without _), maybe in ths way:

```
awk -F';' -vOFS=';' '{ $(NF+1)=$1$2 ; print}'
```

the output expected is:

TABLE1

```
| IDA | IDB | TYPE1 | IDAIDB |
| 123 | X   | 90    |123_X   |
| 123 | X   | 30    |123_X   |
| 123 | Y   | 30    |123_Y   |
```

TABLE2

```
| IDA | IDB | TYPE1 | IDAIDB |
| 123 | X   | 90    | 123_X  |
```

Then I import both tables into my postgresql db (if I don't do the concatenation in bash).
Now I need to create a register of unique combinations of IDAIDB and TYPE1 across all tables and count the number of records for each combination, as follow:

TABLE3

```
| TYPE1 | IDAIDB | COUNT | 
| 90    | 123_X  | 2     | 
| 30    | 123_X  | 1     | 
| 30    | 123_Y  | 1     |
```

To do this I run the following query:

```
COPY (SELECT "TYPE1", "IDAIDB", COUNT (*)
FROM (SELECT "TYPE1", "IDAIDB" FROM "TABLE1" UNION ALL
SELECT "TYPE1", "IDAIDB" FROM "TABLE2") unionall
GROUP BY "TYPE1", "IDAIDB")
TO 'C:\2018\TABLE3.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;
```

At the same time I have extracted from both tables all the unique TYPE1 values and I have assigned another code in the TYPE2 field (I have to do this case by case, it is the reason why I have to edit manually the TYPE2 field in an Excel spreadsheet):

TABLE4

```
 | TYPE1 | TYPE2 | 
 | 30    | 3     | 
 | 90    | 8     |
```

I import both TABLE 3 and TABLE4 in my db.

Then I have to assign to the TABLE3 the most frequent TYPE2 value. The TYPE2 value is stored in the TABLE4. The expected output is:

TABLE3

```
| TYPE1 | IDAIDB | COUNT | TYPE2 |
| 90    | 123_X  | 2     | 8     |
| 30    | 123_X  | 1     | 8     |
| 30    | 123_Y  | 1     | 3     |
```

Finally,I have to join to the TABLE1 and the TABLE2 two new columns COUNT and TYPE2 from the updated TABLE3, using IDAIDB as key field. The expected result is:

TABLE1

```
| IDA | IDB | TYPE1 | IDAIDB | COUNT | TYPE2 |
| 123 | X   | 90    | 123_X  | 2     | 8     |
| 123 | X   | 30    | 123_X  | 1     | 8     |
| 123 | Y   | 30    | 123_Y  | 1     | 3     |
```

TABLE2

```
| IDA | IDB | TYPE1 | IDAIDB | COUNT | TYPE2 |
| 123 | X   | 90    | 123_X  |1      | 8     |
```

In the example above the IDAIDB=123_X takes in both tables 1 and 2 the TYPE2=8 because the most frequent combination of IDAIDB and TYPE1 in the whole db is 123_X 90 (2 records) and not 123_X 30 (1 record)

How can I do this? I am trying to do the job, but I am able to achieve only partial results working  first in bash then in postgresql, I am not able at all to do the last part of the job, that is to assign to the each record the TYPE2 value fromm TABLE2 according to the most frequent combination of IDAIDB and TYPE1. If possible, I would like to do do this only in bash or only postgresql, but it is not mandatory. Thank you in advance

Comment: When you add columns o table1, these columns won't get updated when table2 changes. Are you sure you don't want a one-time report or dynamic view?

Comment: After updating your question this all sounds very unhandy und nasty. Just a tip: Postgres 9.4 added the support to get the most frequent values by using the WITHIN GROUP feature. Have a look at `mode() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY type2)`

Comment: If you think this answer solves your problem. Then accept it by clicking on the checkmark beside it to toggle it from greyed out to fill in. @Luigi Falco

Answer (score 1):

That last column is a bit tricky.  I think this does what you want:

```
select t.ida, t.idb, t.type1, 
       (t.ida || '_' || t.idb) as ida_idb,
       count(*) over (partition by t.ida, t.idb, t.type1) as cnt
from (select distinct on (t1.ida, t1.idb, t1.type) t1.*,
             t2.type2
      from table1 t1 join
           table2 t2
           on t1.type1 = t2.type1
      order by t1.ida, t1.idb, t1.type, count(*) over (partition by t1.ida, t1.idb, t2.type2) desc
     ) t
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback. I have more than one input tables. I am going to edit my question and explein better what is needed.